# How do I change the ~/.bundler directory location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

My home directory is a mounted NFS share and the local root doesn't have permissions to enter my user directory and it causes some errors when bundler removes the cached folders. (See sample output of 'bundle install' below).

I'd like to move the ~/.bundler directory to local disk, if possible. I've been able to move my gems and rvm folders, but I can't for the life of me figure out where to change the bundler directory.

Anyone know how to do this?

```
$ bundle install
Checking out files: 100% (140/140), done.
Checking out files: 100% (9/9), done.
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/rake-0.8.7.gem': Permission denied
Using rake (0.8.7) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/abstract-1.0.0.gem': Permission denied
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/activesupport-3.0.7.gem': Permission denied
Using activesupport (3.0.7) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/builder-2.1.2.gem': Permission denied
Using builder (2.1.2) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/i18n-0.5.0.gem': Permission denied
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/activemodel-3.0.7.gem': Permission denied
Using activemodel (3.0.7) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/erubis-2.6.6.gem': Permission denied
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/rack-1.2.2.gem': Permission denied
Using rack (1.2.2) 
mv: cannot remove `/auto/home2/borgnk/.bundler/tmp/9517/cache/rack-mount-0.6.14.gem': Permission denied
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always customize how `bundle` installs by passing an argument to the installer:

```
bundle install --path /some/path
```

This is useful for the case you highlight, or in cases where a shared directory will be used by different platforms or Ruby versions.

**Update**:

It should be possible to re-position the `~/.bundler` directory by setting your `$HOME` environment variable to be something that will work, which in effect alters what `~` interprets as. Bundler appears to use the method `Gem.user_home` method to determine where to put this file, so if you can fake that out you are set.

This could be as simple as:

```
HOME=/some/home bundle install --path /some/path
```

Comment: i think Kevin is trying to move the .bundler folder. Not where its been installed. By default the gems get installed to default system location. path will change that. But still bulder will cache gems under .bundler.

Comment: I've added some clarification there. You're right about that.

Comment: @RafiB.yes, just did, it worked for me in a similar use case to the one described by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's fairly hard-coded if you look a the [bundler.rb](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/lib/bundler.rb#L144) file. I'd say your best bet would be to fork Bundler and make the change yourself. Or you could always [submit a feature request](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

May be you can create a symbolic link for .bundler and point it to a folder to which bunlder can write. Or else you will have to folk bundler like aNoble suggested.